# Can not pass arguments to CFSwapInt16LittleToHost correctly in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am converting code from Objective-C to Swift and am having trouble with the casting especially for byte operations.  In particular, I am getting the error 'Can not invoke CFSwapInt16LittleToHost with an argument list of (Int16)'.  The Objective-C code is:

```
@interface THSampleDataFilter ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *sampleData;
@end

@implementation THSampleDataFilter

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)sampleData {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _sampleData = sampleData;
}
return self;
}
- (NSArray *)filteredSamplesForSize:(CGSize)size {

    NSMutableArray *filteredSamples = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];        
    NSUInteger sampleCount = self.sampleData.length / sizeof(SInt16);
    NSUInteger binSize = sampleCount / size.width;

    SInt16 *bytes = (SInt16 *) self.sampleData.bytes;

    SInt16 maxSample = 0;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sampleCount; i += binSize) {

    SInt16 sampleBin[binSize];

    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < binSize; j++) {                         
        sampleBin[j] = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(bytes[i + j]);
    }

    SInt16 value = [self maxValueInArray:sampleBin ofSize:binSize];     
    [filteredSamples addObject:@(value)];

    if (value > maxSample) {                                            
        maxSample = value;
    }
}
```

My Swift code is:

```
class THSampleDataFilter : NSObject
{
    var sampleData: NSData?

    init(sampleData: NSData)
{
   super.init()
   self.sampleData = sampleData
}

func filteredSamplesForSize(size: CGSize) -> NSArray?
{
    var filteredSamples = NSMutableArray() 
    var sampleCount:UInt = UInt(Int(self.sampleData!.length) / Int(sizeof(Int16)))
    var binSize = UInt(sampleCount / UInt(size.width))

    var bytes: UnsafePointer<Int16> = UnsafePointer<Int16>(self.sampleData!.bytes)
    var maxSample: Int16 = 0

    for var i:UInt = 0; i < sampleCount; i = i + binSize
        {
            var sampleBin: [Int16] = []

            for var j: UInt = 0; j < binSize; j++
            {
                sampleBin.append(CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(bytes[i + j]))
            }

            let value: Int16 = self.maxValueInArray(sampleBin, size: binSize)
            filteredSamples.addObject(NSNumber(short: value))

            if value > maxSample
            {
                maxSample = value
            }
        }
```

The problem line is:

```
sampleBin.append(CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(bytes[i + j]))
```

This is when I get the error 'Can not invoke CFSwapInt16LittleToHost with an argument list of (Int16)'.  I have tried every combination I can think of.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CFSwapInt16LittleToHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSwapInt16LittleToHost) takes a `UInt16`, not an `Int16`.

```
sampleBin.append(CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(UInt16(bytes[i + j])))
```

or change `bytes` to a `UInt16` pointer.

```
var bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt16> = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(self.sampleData!.bytes)
```

Comment: Hi Jeffery - thank you for pointing that out - I have changed the types to match and the code compiles and works!